# Shell script to access sqlplus

Tags: bash, shell, sqlplus

can anyone help me in wiring a shell script to acess sqlplus . In sqlplus i need to run a sql script and mail the result back to a mail id.

example

```
ls dir ----> has  abc.sql
```

i go to sqlplus and run query by  `==> **sqlplus username/password@instance @abc**`

I want to mail the result to xyz@enterprise.com

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do:

```
sqlplus username/password@instance @abc | mail -s "Email Subject" xyz@enterprise.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I try the above line , the system doesn't do anything. Then i had to cancel                     ^Z[1] + Stopped (SIGTSTP)        sqlplus username/password@instance @abc | mail -s "Email Subject" xyz@enterprise.com

Comment: @misguided: If you do the `sqlplus` command by itself, do you get output to the screen? If you do `echo "hello" | mail -s "test message" xyz@enterprize.com`, do you get that email?

Answer (score 0):

You shuld redirect the output of sqlplus to a file
And then use mailx to send that to specified email id.

Comment: don't need the file, just pipe directly to mailx